# 1990s sci-fi series where humans in armed suits fight robots

Tags: story-identification, robots, tv

I'm looking for the name of a sci-fi series, intended for children. Robots have control over the humans. There is a squad of humans who attack them. Every member in this squad has a badge on their suit, and when they touch this badge the suit becomes armed. This series was not cartoon series, it was performed by real people. The main robot character is very similar in style to Darth Vader in *Star Wars*. The series aired in the 1990s. I am sorry but I can't recall many details.

Comment: Did it involve any Imperial Marches?

Comment: @muntoo, iirc no

Comment: Power on! (cool armour appears)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)

(You should have mentioned seizure-inducing special effects, I could have guessed it sooner)

Intro Video:

Comment: Yeah, that's it :D

Comment: Additional note for B5 fans: Most episodes of this series were written by J. Michael Straczynski, later the Great Maker of Babylon 5, or Larry DiTillio.

Comment: Technology note: The seizure-inducing special effects were an early interactive-TV trick; they enabled the toy line to *detect gunfire on screen and shoot back*.  A neat trick, thankfully never duplicated since.