# Film watched from VHS around 1986 with a team suiting up in full-body suits and masks

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a feature, not an episode. Rented it repeatedly on VHS from a place near my house. 
This was around 1986.

It was a live action, hero-vs-baddies, and looking back, it was pretty *Power Ranger*-y in costuming. There may actually have been more than the one main hero — like a team — but I'm not sure. (I feel like I remember a scene where the guys "suited up" and maybe there were 3 of them? Might've only been the one. I also seem to recall the suit the hero(es) wore were mainly white and silver.) Full head mask when suited up, too.

Also, there might have been something going on with a volcano?

Just a silly movie, but I wonder if anyone remembers it. I'd watch it again, if I knew the first place to look for it.

I know it's not *Ghostbusters*.

Comment: Ultraman? Wore a white/silver (and red) suit, but was supposed to be a robot, not a guy in a suit. Definite "power ranger" costuming. Otherwise, kind of a stretch...

Comment: Hmm, that's getting alot warmer. I'm just tracking it down to preview it better. If nothing else, this is the right direction. Had no idea "Tokusatsu" was a thing, so I've got all kinds of 80s toplists I can browse, now. If I could filter out the results that all look *exactly* like the Power Rangers, it would go faster, lol This is going better than I thought - thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/1990s-sci-fi-series-where-humans-in-armed-suits-fight-robots

Comment: @Otis Unfortunately, according to [site policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) we can't close this question unless the OP comes back to confirm that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Is it [Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)?

[image]

Even though this was a TV series, I remember renting this on VHS as a kid and thinking it was a movie.