# What live-action 80s show had a metal pterodactyl?

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a live-action TV show I saw in the USA on Sundays back in the 80's. It might have been on PBS, so possibly it was British.

It had a (CG?) metal pterodactyl or dragon-looking thing, kinda like [Lazerbeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laserbeak#Transformers%3a_Generation_1) (one of the cassette tapes that comes out of Soundwave in Transformers).

Comment: You might want to clarify the Soundwave is a Transformers reference - I had to look it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like a few other story identification questions on here (e.g. [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27120/i-used-to-watch-the-same-movie-over-and-over-when-i-was-a-kid/) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/1990s-sci-fi-series-where-humans-in-armed-suits-fight-robots)), this show could be *[Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future (1987-88)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)*.

One of the “Bio-Dreads” (monstrous creations that hunt down human survivors of the war between men and machines) on the show was a sort of metal pterodactyl thing called [Soaron](http://soldiersofthefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Soaron), and was portrayed using CGI.

[image: The fearsome (sort of) Soaron]

Comment: Wow, blast from the past! I think thats it.

Comment: @Mazura: hurray! Glad we nailed it down.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you might be thinking of the Terrahawk, one of the ships from [Gerry Anderson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson)'s [Terrahawks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrahawks).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could be, although Terrahawks wasn’t live action but *Supermarionation!!!!!*.