# TV series in the early 90s about war with robots (or aliens)

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was this series I watched in the early 90s, about a group of soldiers fighting against some androids (or aliens, can't remember). 
The enemies definitely looked like androids, but I can't recall if they were robots from Earth or aliens.

The only enemy unit I can remember had wings, with birdy head. There were also terrestrial units.

The enemy's weapons shot lasers. I first thought people were being disintegrated, but later found out they were actually teleported to the enemy's HQ.

I can't remember much more, just that it was on Earth, where all the cities were basically reduced debris and fights would happen through the remains.

Comment: Did the robots travel through time?

Comment: Animated or live-action?

Comment: @kviiri it was live action.

Comment: @WadCheber I don't think so.

Comment: “wings, with birdy head” Hm.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes, a kind of anthropomorphic bird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might this be [yet another](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51716/what-live-action-80s-show-had-a-metal-pterodactyl/51717#51717) [dim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27120/i-used-to-watch-the-same-movie-over-and-over-when-i-was-a-kid/) [memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/1990s-sci-fi-series-where-humans-in-armed-suits-fight-robots) of *[Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future (1987-88)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)*?

One of the “Bio-Dreads” (monstrous creations that hunt down human survivors of the war between men and machines) on the show was a sort of metal pterodactyl thing called [Soaron](http://soldiersofthefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Soaron), and was portrayed using CGI.

[image: The fearsome (sort of) Soaron]

Wings: check. Birdy head: check. All the cities were basically reduced to debris: check.

Comment: That's it! Oh my... didn't remember the fx were so bad :)

Comment: @algiogia: well, they certainly weren’t bad enough for everyone to turn off and forget the show ever happened.

Comment: thank you, this is it!

Comment: @Petrunov It frequently is!

Answer (score 4):

Wondering if this could be Cleopatra 2525?

Comment: Wow, I thought I'd hallucinated that show.

Comment: No. And please don't remind me of that series again :P

Comment: @algiogia Yeah, because Captain Power was SO much better ;)

Comment: I remember (but I could be wrong) the plot wasn't that bad. But Cleopatra... a stripper who get hibernated after breast surgery... Futurama is more realistic :)

Comment: I think that if it had been _Cleopatra 2525_ the OP would have remembered the underwear. ;-) Jennifer Sky (Cleo) once complained that she was being typecast as "a stripper or a slut". Even better: her IMDb profile picture is the cover of the _Maxim_ with that interview.